# dplyr pivot table

Tags: r, pivot, dplyr, tidyr

I want to obtain a pivot table with descending value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

h<-mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  tally() %>%
  spread(gear, n, fill = 0)
h<-h%>% add_rownames("index")

i<-mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%
  tally() %>%
  spread(cyl, n, fill = 0)
```

To obtain the sum of the values

```
j<-i%>%
  select(-1)%>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))

k<-t(j)
k<- as.data.frame(k)
k<-tbl_df(k)
k<-k%>%add_rownames("index")

l<-left_join(h,k,by="index")
l<-l%>%
  select(-1)%>%
  arrange(desc(V1))
```

Is there another way to do the same in dplyr?

Comment: Thanks akrun, your answer is simplfy perfect

Answer (score 11):

We group by 'cyl', 'gear', get the frequency count (`tally()`), reshape from 'long' to 'wide' (using `spread` from `tidyr`), `ungroup` to remove the attributes (previously, it used to work without this),  use `mutate` to create 'V1' as the `sum` of each row (using `rowSums`) and finally `arrange` (`order`) the rows  based on values in 'V1'.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl, gear) %>% 
   tally() %>%
   spread(gear, n, fill=0) %>% 
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(V1= rowSums(.[-1])) %>% 
   arrange(desc(V1))
#    cyl     3     4     5    V1
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     8    12     0     2    14
#2     4     1     8     2    11
#3     6     2     4     1     7
```

Comment: I get the error "Error: incompatible size (3), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1" when trying this (dplyr 0.4.3, tidyr 0.4.1). I can get around this by inserting `data.frame() %>%` between the spread and mutate arguments (Or alternatively dropping the attribute vars ( `attr(h, which = "vars") <- NULL`  before proceeding).

Comment: @JWilliman You need to add `ungroup` between spread and mutate.  I think this was the result of some modifications in the functions between 2015 and 2016.